# String comparing with Date field

Tags: sql

In Table have a `Date` field of type `date` and I get 2 date `from` and `to` as String.

I want to filter the recodrs that exist between these 2 dates.

What will be the best way to select

Comment: You mean you named a field [Date] ? This is a reserved word. You should not do that.

Comment: Tag the dbms used! (Many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time, so the answer will probably be product specific.) Show is sample table data and the expected result!

Answer (score 0):

The best is to transform the string dates into dates using your DBMS provided transformation functions,

Using Oracle for instance, i would write :

```
where 
your_date_field 
   between to_date(from,format_of_from) and to_date(to,format_of_to)
```

Comment: A product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least inform OP (and others) which dbms this is for.

Comment: Or, better yet, transform them into dates *before* they even reach the database system.